# XText grammar generating CDATA

Tags: xml, grammar, cdata, xtext

How to define entity field in XText grammar so XML file generated according to rules of this grammar will contain data of this field wrapped in CDATA section? Is this possibility provided by XText, or do I have to take care of it somehow myself? I have looked into Eclipse [documentation](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html), but haven't found anything so far

Answer (score 0):

What I have asked for is achievable by subclassing `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGenerator`. There you can define custom compilation of entities to XML structure